# Trying to understand directivity of an ultrasonic sensor

Tags: antenna, wave, ultrasound

I am trying to understand this plot of directivity from the following link:

[image]
http://www.nicera.co.jp/pro/ut/pdf/T4010B4(ENG).pdf

How do I read this plot? I can say that at 0 degree , the energy would be  0 db, at close to 60 degree , this is close to -10dB. Am I right ?

But then what is the meaning of  -6dB Full Angle : 100°, I do not see 100 degree anywhere. Even if I imagined I am not able to visualize how it will go to -6dB. Also why they did not show the energy at 100 degree in this plot.

Comment: From the plot,  +/- 50 degrees is at -6dB. So it looks like the 100 degrees refers to Angle over which the device is responsive at >-6dB ; i.e. a 100 degree angle.

Comment: You have already 180 degree in the diagram

Answer (score 3):

You are correct with your interpretation of the plot, yes.

The "-6dB Full Angle : 100°" refers to the spread angle around 0° at which the radiation is greater that -6dB.  That is, ±50° around 0°.  You can see from the plot that the radiation line crosses the -6dB mark at 50° either side of 0°, so the full spread at > -6dB is 50*2 = 100°.

[image]